# I need advice on using filepond and Jquery to read qr code from an image that contains other data

Tags: jquery, qr-code, filepond

I'm a beginner with filepond & jquery and I was wondering if there is the possibility to read the qr code contained in image document during the drag & drop or a way to integrate other scripts or in some other way.

I did a lot of research on the internet but didn't find anything that could help me.